# Webgl rendering slows down on 30Hz monitor in presence of a css animation

Tags: css, electron, webgl

I have an electron app which contains a canvas. I read 1280x720p video frames from the array and use webgl to display it sequentially on the canvas.
Everything works fine on a 60Hz display. When I move the app to external display running at 30Hz (refresh rate of 30), things slow down considerably. I have a css animation on top of canvas. If I remove that css animation, things look good again.

I am relying on requestAnimationFrame callback to invoke webgl draw. From my understanding, on 30Hz monitor requestAnimationFrame callback should get invoked 30 times every second. So I expected drawing to work at 30 fps. But each draw operation is taking around 120 ms. Due to this, drawing fps drops to mere 12-13 fps.
I suspect some sort of interference in rendering due to presence of continuous CSS animation (its a fading icon) on a 30Hz display.
Can somebody provide some insight on it.
Thanks in advance !